# camera in emgu cv,no error is coming but when I am pressing the start button then camera is getting on but no image is capturing

Tags: c#, emgucv

I wrote code for camera in emgu cv,no error is coming but when I am pressing the start button then camera is getting on but no image is capturing.other project image is getting captured.thanks a lot for helped.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;

   namespace camstop
 {
       public partial class cameracapture : Form
    {
          private Capture capture;
           private bool captureinprogress;

    public cameracapture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void processFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imageframe = capture.QueryFrame();
        cameraimagebox.Image = imageframe;
        pictureBox1.Image = imageframe.ToBitmap();
        imageframe.Save(@"E:\\photo\\Mypic.jpg");

    }

    private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureinprogress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnstart.Text = "Start!"; //
                Application.Idle -= processFrame;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
            // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
            btnstart.Text = "Stop!";
            Application.Idle += processFrame;
        }
        captureinprogress = !captureinprogress;
    }
    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }

    private void cameracapture_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Got to the click event and call the btnstart method,for imagebox and button..
If the problem gives in "form"not found then change the namespace name and call the form1 name in program.cs